# Python Weird Printing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make an Enigma machine in Python using ASCII. But my script does weird stuff. If it works with 3 character input , sometimes it prints one character, sometimes 2 and sometimes 3. I have no clue why. Heres the script.

```
import random

encrypt = {65:90, 66:90, 67:72, 68:78, 69:77, 70:83, 71:87, 72:67, 73:73, 74:89, 75:84, 76:81, 77:69, 78:68, 79:79, 80:66, 81:76, 82:82, 83:70, 84:75, 85:85, 86:86, 87:71, 88:88, 89:74, 90:65}
```

encrypted = []

```
r1 = random.randint(1,26)
r2 = random.randint(1,26)
r3 = random.randint(1,26)
security = str(r1) + "a" + "-" + str(r2) + "b" + "-" + str(r3) + "c"

input_en = input("Zadejte text, ktery chcete zasifrovat (pouzivejte velka      pismena): ")

for i in range(0,len(input_en)):
    coded = input_en[i]
    coded = ord(coded)
    coded = encrypt[coded]
    full = r1 + r2 + r3
    coded += full
    while(coded > 90):
        rekt = coded - 90
        coded = 65 + rekt
        continue
    done = chr(coded)
    encrypted.append(done)
    r1 += 1
    if r1 > 26:
        r1 = 1
        break
    r2 += 1
    if r2 > 26:
        r2 = 1
        break
    r3 += 1
    if r3 > 26:
        r3 = 1
        break
    continue
print(encrypted)
print("Bezpecnostni kod je",security)
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: "does weird stuff." and "sometimes it prints one character, sometimes 2 and sometimes 3." are pretty vague problem descriptions. Could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42983423/edit) your question and include your example `inputs`/`current outputs`, and also `inputs` / *`expected`* outputs? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things in your code that aren't right:

Firstly you don't need a `continue` statement at the end of your `for` or `while` loops to get them to return to the start. Since Python uses whitespace to indicate blocks of code, simply unindenting at the end of a loop is enough, i.e:

```
while coded > 90:
    [do stuff]
    continue
done = chr(coded)
[the rest of your code]

--- Should be changed to ---

while coded > 90:
    [do stuff]
done = chr(coded)
[the rest of your code]
```

Additionally, the `break` command in your `if` statements aren't doing what you think they are. It looks like you're using `break` to indicate the end of the `if` block, but this is another example where all you need to do is unindent the next piece of code.

The `break` command exits the nearest *loop*, which in this case means they are exiting the main `for` loop, which cuts off your loop prematurely and doesn't encode all the characters.

Comment: Hi. I tried removing the "break" command and it actually worked! Tried it like 50 times with no problem. I am having issue with the encryption being just way too obvious, but thats not the purpose of this thread. Its easy to fix anyways. Thanks a lot!